# TEMP table alternatives for pl/pgsql

Tags: postgresql, performance, temporary-tables, upsert, postgresql-performance

I am trying to emulate `MERGE` behavior with pl/pgsql:

```
-- Generate the data from funtion
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_x  (id int, id2 int, data text, created_at timestamp, updated_at timestamp)  ON COMMIT DROP;
INSERT INTO temp_x SELECT * FROM set_gernating_function(p);

-- DELETE record with same id2
DELETE FROM x WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp_x WHERE temp_x.id=x.id) AND id2=p.id2;

-- UPSERT by (id, id2)
INSERT INTO x
    SELECT * FROM temp_x z
  ON CONFLICT(id, id2) DO UPDATE
    SET
      updated_at=excluded.updated_at,
      data=excluded.data;
```

But the temp table usage is generating bloat in `pg_class` and `pg_attr` table *very* fast -- Faster then I could do vacuum -- and affect other queries. Any idea?

There are some restrictions:

1. Preserve the `created_at` time if the id already exist
2. x have a delete-trigger, so no unnecessary delete.
3. The `set_generating_function` is slow
4. The size for temp_x is small. (< 50)
5. The run rate is very high (thousands per second)

Comment: The delete statement in your question seems to be incomplete. The condition `AND id2=p.id` refers to an alias `p` that is not present. Should that be part of the co-related sub-query?

Comment: Can't the temp table have a session lifetime instead of a transaction lifetime? Or are you doing this process only once per session?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the alias `p` is a custom type from function parameter.  Should be irrelevance here.

Comment: @DanielVérité I have doing ~10 process per transaction; millions per session.  Per transaction temp table does not help much.  Per session temp table make the temp table bloat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the temp table:

You can do this in a single statement:

```
with temp_x (id, id2, data, created_at, updated_at) AS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM set_gernating_function(p)
), deleted as (
  DELETE FROM x 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM temp_x 
                    WHERE temp_x.id = x.id) 
    AND id2=p.id2
)
-- UPSERT by (id, id2)
INSERT INTO x
SELECT * 
FROM temp_x z
  ON CONFLICT(id, id2) DO UPDATE
    SET updated_at = excluded.updated_at,
        data = excluded.data;
```